# Не остановка работы googl clab

Tags: нейронные-сети

Создал нейросеть. Всё работает в программе googl clab. Но после закрытия всё сбрасывается и обучение нейросети нужно делать снова. Это можно предотвратить или посоветуйте сервер для python.

Comment: Это штатный режим работы этого сервиса. Подключите гугл диск и сохраняйте промежуточные этапы на него.